# Controlling PI's GPIO over Wifi (WebIOPi alternatives)

Tags: networking, wireless, software-installation, webiopi

I'm looking for alternatives to [WebIOPi](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/). 
I need to be able to control PI's GPIO through a UI displayed in the browser (with a Customizable UI ofcourse)

Any suggestions?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebIOPi provides a REST interface for GPIO control.  You can write any UI you want on top of that.

https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/RESTAPI

Answer (score 2):

Try BerryIO. It's an outstanding piece of software.

http://frozenmist.co.uk/downloads/berryio/

Comment: Looks good. Thanks :) Can I customize it? (Forgot to mention customization earlier)

Comment: Since it's on Github you could clone it to your own Git repository and modify the existing code to add/removing things. If you're looking just to change how the frontend looks, check the www directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try WebGPIO at  Github and still active in this 2018 :

https://github.com/ThisIsQasim/WebGPIO

The WebGPIO is Flask based. So you need to have Flask installed. Also install the pyyaml for the yaml framework to run WebGPIO.

```
pip install flask pyyaml
```

Beside Flask, you can als try to use Bottle. Both Flask and Bottle can be used to run Python script via web browser (HTML).

Comment: The other two answers before are very bad examples. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: go for flask or bottle to run python script via html

Comment: if you want to modify from what somebody build, try WebGPIO